# sich einer Sache (Gen.) erinnern?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case

Ein Satz aus Dem Parfum von Patrick Süskind:

> Zehntausend, hunderttausend spezifische Eigengerüche hatte er
> gesammelt und hielt sie zu seiner Verfügung, so deutlich, so beliebig,
> daß er sich nicht nur ihrer erinnerte, wenn er sie wiederroch, sondern
> daß er sie tatsächlich roch, wenn er sich ihrer wiedererinnerte....

Bei dem Verb "erinnern" habe ich diese grammatische Konstruktion nie gesehen. Anstatt das erwartete "an sie" direkt vor "erinnerte" zu schreiben, schreibt Süskind "ihrer," was aussieht, wie es im Genitiv steht. Was hat es mit diesem "ihrer" auf sich?

Comment: Es gibt eine (kleine, <20) Anzahl von Verben im Deutschen, die den Genitiv fordern (können). Es empfiehlt sich, die einfach auswendig zu lernen, damit du dich bei der nächsten Begegnung nicht wieder wunderst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beides ist möglich und richtig:

Sich an etwas oder jemanden erinnern (an + Akk)

Sich einer Sache oder Person erinnern (Gen)

Die Genitivkonstruktion ist ungewöhnlich (interessanterweise finde ich sie auf [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erinnern) nicht, aber [wiktionary kennt es unter Variante [2]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erinnern)) und heute kaum noch gebräuchlich und ist mindestens gehobene Sprache. Man kann auch argumentieren, dass es veraltet ist. Tendenziell denke ich, dass man es gelegentlich antrifft, wenn 'einer Person erinnern' im Sinne von und analog zu 'einer Person gedenken' gebraucht wird.